# Is there a way to capture DataGridView KeyPress event without editing control showing?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to be able to make the cell's value only have certain characters. However, I won't have the editing control showing since certain columns are read only. The common solution is either to use this method (shown below) or do the keyPress event for the entire form. The last solution, unfortunately, gives you the events for *all* the keys pressed.

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
   DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl tb =(DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)e.Control;
   tb.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(dataGridViewTextBox_KeyPress);

   e.Control.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(dataGridViewTextBox_KeyPress);
}
```

I have tried using the native "KeyDown" event but it's never called. Any suggestions?

Comment: Validating user input to the cell is usually done via the editing control, what is wrong with that approach? If the cell is read-only, the user cannot edit any invalid characters anyway...

Comment: I did try the EditingControlShowing event, and it didn't call when I hit the keys either. I thought it was connected to the "pencil" marker showing.

Answer (score 0):

To capture the event, you need to assign an event handler. I copied some Microsoft code that shows how:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        **this.textBox1.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.KeyPressWork);**
        this.textBox1.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.KeyDownWork);
    }

    private void KeyDownWork(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.KeyCode.ToString(), "KeyDown");

        KeysConverter kc = new KeysConverter();
        MessageBox.Show(kc.ConvertToString(e.KeyCode), "KeyDown");
    }

    private void KeyPressWork(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.KeyChar.ToString(), "KeyPress");
    }
}
```

The textBox1 is receiving the address of the handler in this case. Try the same with a cell. I have done this with a DataGridView for cell formatting so I know it works. NOTE: This is a necro answer which will help others who find this article in the future.